# How to avoid distribution over multiple generic type parameters in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I didn't know how to formulate my question properly, so I'll give an example.

```
type ValueType = "NUM" | "STR";

type TypeOf<T>
    = T extends "NUM" ? number
    : T extends "STR" ? string
    : never;

interface TypedValue<T = ValueType> {
    type: T;
    data: TypeOf<T>;
}


// Compiles, as intended
const test1: TypedValue = { type: "NUM", data: 123 };

// Does not compile, as intended
const test2: TypedValue<"NUM"> = { type: "NUM", data: "123" };

// Should not compile, but does...
const test3: TypedValue = { type: "NUM", data: "123" };
```

It seems that Typescript generates many concrete types for the interface `TypedValue`:

so

```
interface TypedValue<T = ValueType, D = TypeOf<T>>
```

corresponds to

```
interface TypedValue<"NUM", number> 
interface TypedValue<"NUM", string> 
interface TypedValue<"NUM", never> 
interface TypedValue<"STR", number> 
interface TypedValue<"STR", string> 
interface TypedValue<"STR", never>
```

and maybe more, while I actually want this generic type to correspond to just

```
interface TypedValue<"NUM", number> 
interface TypedValue<"STR", string>
```

How can I avoid this type distribution, e.g. how can I tie one type parameter to another type parameter in typescript?

I know about the trick to suppress type distribution using

```
type TypeOf<T>
    = [T] extends ["NUM"] ? number
    : [T] extends ["STR"] ? string
    : never;
```

But I can't seem solve the puzzle myself, and I really want to dig deeper in this magical type system, so any help is welcome :) Pretty sure jcalz knows how to tackle this ;)

**EDIT** *It finally clicked after Titian Cernicova-Dragomir answer! Personally I understand the solution better with the following code snippet:*

```
type Pairs1<T> = [T, T];
type Pairs2<T> = T extends (infer X) ? [X, X] : never;

type P1 = Pairs1<"A" | "B">; // => ["A" | "B", "A" | "B"]  
type P2 = Pairs2<"A" | "B">; // => ["A", "A"] | ["B" | "B"]
```

What seems to happen, the Typescript compiler will check `T extends (infer X)` for each union member `"A"|"B"`, which always succeeds, but it now binds the matching type variable to a **non-union** type variable `X`. And the `infer X` is actually not needed, but it helped me to understand it better.

Infinite gratitude, I've been struggling with this for a long time.

So now I finally understand the following excerpt from the Typescript manual:

*In instantiations of a distributive conditional type `T extends U ? X : Y`, references to `T` within the conditional type are resolved to **individual constituents of the union type** (i.e. `T` refers to the individual constituents after the conditional type is distributed over the union type). Furthermore, references to `T` within `X` have an additional type parameter constraint `U` (i.e. `T` is considered assignable to `U` within `X`).*

Comment: jcalz is probably still asleep, you'll have to settle for my answer :)

Comment: A simple and generic solution to prevent distribution of union types is to box them through an interface https://lorefnon.tech/2019/05/02/using-boxing-to-prevent-distribution-of-conditional-types/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is no so much with the conditional part of your solution but more with the way variables type annotations work coupled with default type parameters.

If not type is specified for a variable its type will be inferred. If you specify a type, no inference will occur. So when you say `const test3: TypedValue`, no inference for the generic type parameter will occur and the default value for the type parameter will be used. So `const test3: TypedValue` is equivalent to `const test3: TypedValue<"NUM" | "STR">` which is equivalent to  `const test3: { type: "NUM" | "STR"; data: number | string; }`

Since this is the type of the variable, the object literal will just be checked against the type and it is compatible with it (`type` is `"NUM"`, compatible with `"NUM" | "STR"`, `data` is of type `string` compatible with `string | number`)

You can convert your type into a true discriminated union using exactly the distributive behavior or conditional types:

```
type ValueType = "NUM" | "STR";

type TypeOf<T>
    = T extends "NUM" ? number
    : T extends "STR" ? string
    : never;

type TypedValue<T = ValueType> = T extends any ? {
    type: T;
    data: TypeOf<T>;
}: never;

// Compiles, as intended
const test1: TypedValue = { type: "NUM", data: 123 }; 

// Does not compile, as intended
const test2: TypedValue<"NUM"> = { type: "NUM", data: "123" };

// does not compile now
const test3: TypedValue = { type: "NUM", data: "123" };
```

With the definition above `TypedValue` without a type parameter is equivalent to :

```
{
    type: "NUM";
    data: number;
} | {
    type: "STR";
    data: string;
}
```

This means that a `type` to `STR` can never be compatible with a `data` of type `number` and a `type` to `NUM` can never be compatible with a `data` of type `string`.

The conditional type in `TypedValue` is not used to express an actual condition, every `T` will extend `any`. The point of the conditional type is to distribute over `T`. This means that if `T` is a union, the result will be the type `{ type: T; data: TypeOf<T>; }` applied to every member of the union. Read more about the distributive behavior of conditional types [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: That is amazing, thanks a lot! However, I do not understand how this works, since every type `extends any` no? So why does the condition filter anything? Could you give me some references to read in order to understand this better?

Comment: @Ziriax added an explanation at the end, we just use the distributive part of conditional types we don't actually care about the condition.